# Tracking object changes rails (Active Model Dirty)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to track changes on a method just like we are tracking changes on record attributes using the Active Model Dirty.

At the moment I'm using this method to check changes to a set of attributes.

```
def check_updated_attributes
    watch_attrs = ["brand_id", "name", "price", "default_price_tag_id", "terminal_usp", "primary_offer_id", "secondary_offer_id"]
    if (self.changed & watch_attrs).any?
      self.tag_updated_at = Time.now
    end
end
```

However the attribute price is not a normal attribute with a column but a method defined in the model that combines two different attributes.

This is the method:

```
    def price
        if manual_price 
            price = manual_price
        else
            price = round_99(base_price)
        end
        price.to_f
    end
```

Is there a way to track changes on this price method? or does this only work on normal attributes?

**Edit:** Base price method:

```
def base_price(rate = Setting.base_margin, mva = Setting.mva)
    (cost_price_map / (1 - rate.to_f)) * ( 1 + mva.to_f)
end
```

cost_price and manual_price are attributes with columns it the terminal table.

Comment: Can't you just watch the attributes `manual_price` and `base_price` in stead of `price`?

Comment: No, because base_price is a method also, that only changes if the cost_price attribute changes enough to round up or down 100. That means, not all changes in the cost_price results in a change in price.

Comment: Because `price` is only a getter method without a setter you just can't watch it getting dirty. Watch `cost_price` and compare the old value with the new value and determine if it has changed enough to trigger the change of `tag_updated_at`.

Comment: @zwippie could you give me an example of this as an answer? I think it will work, just don't know how i get the old value of the attribute and compare it to the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved it.

I had to create a custom method named price_changed? to check if the price had changed.

```
def price_changed?
    if manual_price 
        manual_price_changed?
    elsif cost_price_map_changed?
        round_99(base_price) != round_99(base_price(cost_price = read_attribute(:cost_price_map)))
    else
        false
    end
end
```

This solved the problem, although not a pretty solution if you have many custom attributes.